# Append zero bytes to a file

Tags: swift, filehandle

Is there a way to append zero bytes to a file without having to create a empty Data value?

```
let handle : FileHandle = ...
let count : Int = ...
try handle.seekToEnd()
try handle.write(contentsOf: Data(repeating: 0, count: count))
```

Comment: The `Data` that you are creating is not "empty" at all. It's full of zeros. And anyway, what is wrong with creating a `Data`?

Comment: Yes it's full of zero bytes, obviously. My point is this code creates a Data value of zero values only to append them to a file. What's the point in allocating memory of zero bytes only to discard that data immediately.

Comment: You can also open file for appending instead of seeking to end.

Comment: My use case is more random access which may or may not involve appending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append null bytes to a file with the [`truncate(atOffset:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/3172532-truncate) method. From the documentation:

> Truncates or extends the file represented by the file handle to a
> specified offset within the file and puts the file pointer at that
> position.
>
> If the file is extended (if offset is beyond the current end of file),
> the added characters are null bytes.

No data value or write operation is needed for this purpose.

Example:

```
let handle : FileHandle = ...
let numberOfBytesToAppend: UInt64 = ...
var size = try handle.seekToEnd()     // Get current size
size += numberOfBytesToAppend         // Compute new size
try handle.truncate(atOffset: size)   // Extend file
try handle.close()
```

A system call trace with `dtruss` shows that extending the file is done efficiently with the [`ftruncate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/ftruncate.2.html) system call:

```
$ sudo dtruss /path/to/program
  ...
  920/0x3c0b:  open("file.txt\0", 0x1, 0x0)      = 3 0
  920/0x3c0b:  fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFEE381B358, 0x0)         = 0 0
  920/0x3c0b:  lseek(0x3, 0x0, 0x2)      = 6000 0
  920/0x3c0b:  lseek(0x3, 0x1B58, 0x0)       = 7000 0
  920/0x3c0b:  ftruncate(0x3, 0x1B58, 0x0)       = 0 0
  920/0x3c0b:  close(0x3)        = 0 0
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`write(contentsOf:)` takes any `DataProtocol` as a parameter. You can create a [`Repeated<UInt8>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/repeated), which conforms to `DataProtocol`, using `repeatElement`:

```
try fileHandle.write(contentsOf: repeatElement(0, count: someCount))
```

`Repeated<T>` is an efficient representation of a collection with only one unique element repeated n times. According to the [implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/eec4b26deee34edb7664ddd9c1222492a399d122/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/Collections%2BDataProtocol.swift#L48), when `someCount > 0`, this will only create one `Data` instance containing just one 0.

Comment: It may be relevant or not, but I'll just mention that this will execute `someCount` write system calls, each writing a single byte.

Comment: @MartinR You're right. That is my oversight. And wow, I never would have known that something called `truncate` would extend a file :)

Comment: Oh, that doesn’t sound very efficient.

Comment: @user965972: You'll probably not notice the difference, unless you are appending gigabytes :)